# Remove an element from array and free memory allocated to it

Tags: c++

As mentioned in the title, how to free the memory allocated after deleting an element from array. Here is my code:

```
// VectorGraphic.h
#include "GraphicElement.h"
#include <string>
#ifndef VECTOR_GRAPHIC_H
#define VECTOR_GRAPHIC_H

class VectorGraphic
{
    unsigned int numGraphicElements;
    GraphicElement* pElements;
public:
    VectorGraphic(){        
        numGraphicElements = 0;
        //pElements = new GraphicElement();
        pElements = new GraphicElement[sizeof(GraphicElement)+1];
    }
    ~VectorGraphic()
    {                       
        if (pElements){
            delete[]pElements;
            //pElements = NULL;
        }

    }

    void DeleteGraphicElement(){
        cout << "Deleting a Graphic Element" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the index of the Graphic Element you wish to delete" << endl;
        int index; 
        cin >> index; 
        if (index > numGraphicElements){
            cout << "Element is not found at specified index";
            return;
        }
        else{
            for (int i = 0; i < numGraphicElements; i++){
                if (i == index){
                    for (int j = i; j < numGraphicElements - 1; j++){
                        pElements[j] = pElements[j + 1];
                    }
                    //delete pElements[numGraphicElements - 1];  //<-Here. This statement shows an error saying "Expression must have pointer type."
                    numGraphicElements--;

                    cout << "Graphic Element deleted successfully" << endl; 
                    break; 
                }
            }

        }

    }
};

#endif
```

I have commented the line in DeleteGraphicElement() function where the requirement/error is.
I tried using `delete pElements[numGraphicElements - 1];` but This statement shows an error saying "Expression must have pointer type."

Comment: That is complicated. You need to delete the last element and shift them, because arrays are continuous, you can't just free an element in the middle.

Comment: What led you to believe that you need to "free memory" as part of deleting an element from the array? Based on the scant information given, I see nothing that needs to be freed.

Comment: Better not use `new` and `delete` yourself. Push the burden to get it right to  [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) or standard containers.

Comment: `delete` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: _"Push the burden to get it right to smart pointers"_ That's a new one! You'll have to explain it to me one day :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm avoiding `new`and `delete` as much as possible (there are uses of course). Should we have (or do we have already) a canonical Q&A for that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : I was referring to the English construction, actually. ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah my poor English again, sorry I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Argh! Now a comma splice! You have awoken the beast; you know that, right? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125281/discussion-between---and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That sounds dangerous...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm open all the time ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U38HmSSAGSo

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to have an array of pointers to be able to `delete` a single element of your array.

You can shift all following elements back one place, but reallocation of `new`ed memory is not possible with just the standard tools.

Or you can allocate a new array and copy all elements that you want to it.

But the easiest way is to simply use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase). That way you don't have to worry about this and the [rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) that you're currently breaking.